# How to get the value of a dynamic parameter via pipeline?

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing a powershell cmdlet in C# and I am stuck in a problem. I know how to retrieve value of a parameter from pipeline.
I do it by adding 'ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true' on the property decorated with Parameter attribute. I am doing the same for the properties defined in a class containing dynamic parameters. However, the dynamic parameters are always null.
What could be wrong?

```cs
public class ActiveDirectorySpecificParameters
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty]
        public string Domain { get; set; }
    }
```

and then in the cmdlet class implementing IDynamicParameters, I have the following code:

```cs
public object GetDynamicParameters()
        {
            switch (IdentityStoreType)
            {
                case Common.Enums.IdentityStoreType.ActiveDirectory:
                    _parameterSetContext = new DynamicParameters.ActiveDirectorySpecificParameters();
                    break;
                case Common.Enums.IdentityStoreType.WindowsAzure:
                    _parameterSetContext = new DynamicParameters.AzureSpecificParameters();
                    break;
                case Common.Enums.IdentityStoreType.GSuite:
                    _parameterSetContext = new DynamicParameters.GSuiteSpecificParameters();
                    break;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
            return _parameterSetContext;
        }
```

Comment: Post the code of that class

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have edited the question and posted the code where the GetDynamicParameters is being implemented.